# ImportError: No module named nltk (pydev,python 2.7.8,eclipse luna, nltk, windows 8.1)

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, nltk

1. I installed jre 32 bit
2. Installed eclipse luna 32 bit
3. Installed Python 2.7.8
4. Installed nltk via .exe from their site

I created a pydev project and imported two .py files one of which includes the nltk import. In the pydev project package explorer under python->System Libs->Lib/site-packages I see the nltk package there (due to win32 .exe from nltk site). In addition there is the following folder nltk-3.0.0b2-py3.4egg-info and a readme. When I run the the project I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\CUBoulder\Courses\CSCI 5832\assignments\Assignment1\limerick.py", line 7, in <module>
    import nltk
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

I tried to remove the interpreter from window->preferences and adding it again to refresh. I also removed \Lib\site-packages from System Libs manually and added it again. I also restarted eclipse several times. I still got the same error.

Please offer advice or direct to me a page.

Comment: The [download page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk) indicates that the binary for windows (which you presumably installed) is for Python 2.6. Make sure this is OK (hint: if nltk includes DLLs, it probably isn't). Also, use the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on all the DLLs that were installed by the exe. You might be missing a dependency.

Comment: Try installing from here - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Might be a usual 'python under windows' problem. I also wonder is it really 32-bit windows you are running?